# Find the last occurence of a needle in a haystack

Tags: regex, textpad

In Textpad, is it possible to find the last occurence of a string within a string, so, for instance...

Find the last occurrence of `_` within

```
FF_SF_FIRE_STRATEGY_G
```

So that you can then obtain either `FF_SF_FIRE_STRATEGY` or `G`

?

UPDATE: This solves half the problem: `_[A-Z]\>`

Comment: How does `_[A-Z]\>` solve the problem? `\>` doesn't appear anywhere in your example.

Comment: @caustin in textpad, I think it means the end of the string, but I may have misunderstood

Comment: I don't use textpad, but I'd be surprised if that were the case. Can you post your full input?

Comment: Are you within a substitution process by this? Why not to use `^\(.*\)_\(.*\)$`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a negative lookahead based regex:

```
_(?!\S*_)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uv9h6T/2)

Here `(?!\S*_)` is a negative lookahead that asserts that we don't have any more `_` following 0 or more non-whitespace characters on right hand side.

Comment: I think TextPad's implementation of Regex is a little different

Comment: textpad allows lookahead expression, See this: https://superuser.com/questions/1251842/textpad-8-regular-expression-with-multiple-conditions/1252066#1252066

Comment: Well, it doesn't allow *this* one :-( - version 5.4.2, if it makes any difference

Comment: The answer appears to be to upgrade!

Answer (score 0):

According to [textpad](https://www.textpad.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=12375) the regex syntax it used before v7 was POSIX and later it adopted Perl regular expressions. So best is to upgrade your textpad else the following regex attempts to match `_` and captures its preceding / following non-whitespace characters:

```
\(^|[[:blank:]]\)\([^[:blank:]]*\)_\([^[:blank:]_]*\)\([[:blank:]]|$\)
```

It has 4 capturing groups and what you need is hold by `\2` and `\3`.

See a [Perl compatible demo here](https://regex101.com/r/8Sz1wa/1)